# android jump to a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

have done a project with buttons to allow me to navigate on the web but I'm getting an error and my app is stopping right after the splashscreen. any help??

[image: the codes]

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest add following `<activity />` tag after your `MainActivity`'s `<activity>` block:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LMCome"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: i tried it and it stopped showing my splashscreen but showing my app with some errors on the buttons

Comment: @Chris_Colorado17 Your app may be encountering another error. If it is a different kind of error, you can post a new Question after accepting my answer to finish this Q&A.